# Making an embed on Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so im making a discord bot and i want it to send an embed when i type **hy!help**
so i used the format on discord.js documantion and so far my code looks like this

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    token: "pls-no-hack-ty"
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    //do stuff lol
});

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content === "hy!help") {
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Some title')
            .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
            .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
            .setDescription('Some description here')
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
                { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
                { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            )
            .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
            .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
    channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        }  } )
```

But i get an `channel dot defined` error.

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks -rly907

Comment: Also if you are wondering the embed guide is [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last line instead of `channel.send(exampleEmbed);` do

```
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to user [message.channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel)[.send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) it can't use `channel.send`

```js
message.channel.send(Embed);
```